# find edge in image

Tags: matlab, math, edge-detection, matlab-guide

How can I detect the edges in an image without using method 'edge', with only using mathematical operations (matrix or Derived or div or any other)? Indeed, how can I rewrite the function `edge` by using the algorithm  `Canny` or `sobel` or any other?

For example:

[image]

pink rectangle  256*256
black rectangle 127*127

**Answer:[Canny Tutorial](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~nk752/Research/cannyTut2.html)**

Comment: Why do you want to re-write it when a perfectly useable function already exists? Do you wish to customise `edge` in some way? You can use both the canny and sobel algorithms with `edge`.

Answer (score 2):

You state that you wish to use Canny, Sobel or another algorithm. These can both be used in edge. Try for example:

```
BW = edge(I,'canny');
```

where I is your image matrix. If you are interested in finding out how `edge` works, type

```
edit edge
```

into your command window. You will then get to see MATLAB's own implementation.

You may wish to reimplement `edge` from scratch, to gain a good understanding of how image processing algorithms work. If so, I would direct you towards the following sources:

- [The Canny wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector)
- [The Sobel wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator)
- I personally found [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Computer-Vision-Processing-Cornerstones-Computing/dp/0333994515/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1333559938&sr=8-6) an excellent reference for getting to grips with the basics of things like filters and edge detectors.

For your specific example with the rectangles, it is quite possible to use `edge` to find the edges. The one trick you have to do is to convert the rgb image to a grayscale one, using `rgb2gray`. Try for example:

```
rgb_image = imread('iarLe.png');
gray_image = rgb2gray(rgb_image);
edge_image = edge(gray_image);
imshow(edge_image);
```

[image]

Comment: You still haven't explained why you want someone else to help you to do this when there is a very well implemented version, with source code available, in MATLAB already. Why do you need a new version of `edge`?

Comment: Because in his university they forgot to buy the package that includes `edge` :-P

Comment: @Nathan, I would believe that if it weren't for the specific requirements such as only using plus minus divide etc. I think this question is missing a tag.

Comment: do you think so?  Let's ask... @user1263390, is this a homework question?